# How to account number of each column value in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, counting

I have Matrix A:

```
A= [ 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 3 3 0 0;
     0 1 1 0 0 2 2 2 2 3 3 0 0 ];
```

and I want to make another matrix B, so that this matrix contains the number of value occurences of the original matrix A: ie each `ii`th row of `B` contains how many times `ii` occurs in the corresponding columns of A. The number 0 may be ignored.

For example: in the 2nd column of A, only the number 1 occurs, to be specific two times --> hence B(1,2) = 2 and B(other,2) = 0.

For my example matrix A, the output should be

```
Res = [ 1 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
        0 0 0 1 1 2 2 1 1 0 0 0 0;
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 ];
```

Comment: Can you clarify this? I don't understand what you are asking given that example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
A= [ 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 3 3 0 0;
     0 1 1 0 0 2 2 2 2 3 3 0 0 ];


cell2mat(arrayfun(@(b) sum(A == b),nonzeros(unique(A)), 'UniformOutput', false))
```

This results in

```
ans =

     1     2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     1     2     2     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     2     2     0     0
```

If, as asked in the comments, the matrix a has three dimensions, you need to sum the result along the third dimension:

```
sum(cell2mat(arrayfun(@(b) sum(A == b,1),nonzeros(unique(A)), 'UniformOutput', false)),3)
```

Comment: but if A has more than 1 value matrix (I mean that val(:,:,1)...val (:,:,2) ext. how can I modify your code?

Comment: Then you have to take the sum of the result. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Mr. Muster, I still cannot try using your code. I mean that I have Matrix A which has some value (val(:,:,1)...val(:,:,n)), I wanna know it for each value of matrix A. did you know what I mean Mr?

Comment: @FebriDwiLaksono: Please pardon me,  but actually I do not understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

This also is an opportunity for the ([under-appreciated](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/02/20/under-appreciated-accumarray/)) [accumarray](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html)

```
A= [ 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 3 3 0 0;
     0 1 1 0 0 2 2 2 2 3 3 0 0 ];
N = size(A,2);
result = zeros(max(A(:)),N);

for ii=1:N
    s = accumarray(nonzeros(A(:,ii)),1);
    result(1:numel(s),ii) = s;
end
```

too bad only that accumarray can't do it all in one call :(

### EDIT

Got it all in one accumarray call: :p

```
A= [ 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 3 3 0 0;
     0 1 1 0 0 2 2 2 2 3 3 0 0 ];
N = size(A);
C = repmat(1:N(2),N(1),1);

result = accumarray([A(:)+1 C(:)], 1);
result = result(2:end,:)
```

### EDIT2

If you have a 3 dimensional input matrix, it's easiest to first transform it into a 2 dimensional matrix and then process it using the above. The following code does this transform:

```
% example data:
A3d = repmat(A,[1 1 2])
A2d = reshape(permute(A3d,[1 3 2]),[],size(A3d,2))
```

Result:

```
A3d(:,:,1) =
 1     1     0     2     2     2     2     0     0     3     3     0     0
 0     1     1     0     0     2     2     2     2     3     3     0     0
A3d(:,:,2) =
 1     1     0     2     2     2     2     0     0     3     3     0     0
 0     1     1     0     0     2     2     2     2     3     3     0     0


A2d =
 1     1     0     2     2     2     2     0     0     3     3     0     0
 0     1     1     0     0     2     2     2     2     3     3     0     0
 1     1     0     2     2     2     2     0     0     3     3     0     0
 0     1     1     0     0     2     2     2     2     3     3     0     0
```

Comment: Mr. Struyf, If I wanna use your code for matrix A with 3 dimention, How can I do it?

Comment: What do you want then? that you not look at a cross-sectional plane then instead of a column now?

Comment: @GuntherStruyf: +1 ACCUMARRAY is the go-to function when doing counting

Answer (score 1):

You could do this is one function call:

```
Res = histc(A, 1:3);
```

result as expected:

```
Res =
     1     2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     1     2     2     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     2     2     0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative using the SPARSE function (similar to [@GuntherStruyf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11608886/97160)'s second solution using ACCUMARRAY)

```
c = repmat(1:size(A,2), [size(A,1) 1]);
M = full(sparse(A(:)+1, c(:), 1));
M = M(2:end,:);
```

The result:

```
M =
     1     2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     1     2     2     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     2     2     0     0
```